# How to get more result in youtube search result by using youtube api?

Tags: python, youtube-data-api, youtube-dl

I'm using youtube-v3-api to get search list, by using "nextPageToken", I can only get about 500 result, but page infomation showed it contain more than 200000 result, how to get more?

```
def Search(sKeyWord):
"""Input search keyword, return search link list of youtube
Args:
    Input:
        sKeyWord: Search keyword
    Output:
        lVideos: A list of searched videos
"""
# gdr = googleapiclient.discovery.Resource
iMax = 50
gdrYoutube = build(
    YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

sPageToken = ""
lVideos = []
dictResponse = gdrYoutube.search().list(
    q=sKeyWord,
    part='id,snippet',
    maxResults=iMax,
    pageToken=sPageToken
    ).execute()

while(dictResponse.get("nextPageToken")):
    sPageToken = dictResponse["nextPageToken"]
    for dictSearchResult in dictResponse.get('items', []):
        if dictSearchResult['id']['kind'] == 'youtube#video':
            """
            lVideos.append(
                '%s (%s)' % (
                    dictSearchResult['snippet']['title'],
                    dictSearchResult['id']['videoId']))
            """
            lVideos.append(dictSearchResult['id']['videoId'])
    dictResponse = gdrYoutube.search().list(
        q=sKeyWord,
        part='id,snippet',
        maxResults=iMax,
        pageToken=sPageToken
        ).execute()

return lVideos
```

Comment: Have you checked to see the API limits?

Comment: There used to be ways of getting around the 500 hits max on the youtube api, but they are kinda hacky. See the comments to this article: http://truelogic.org/wordpress/2017/06/20/7-youtube-data-api-paging-maxresults/